# Correct time to delete persistent store to delete all entries of an entity

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data, persistent

I am using an UITableViewController containing a UITableView and an UISearchTableView.
The table lists e.g. 1000 entries. I want to provide the user a button to delete all 
entries of a specific entity. Because looping over all managed objects and saving the context takes a very long time, I thought of deleting by removing the persistent store and rebuilding the stack.

Now to my questions: How can I do this in the UITableViewController? I don't want to restart the app for deletion so I want to move the code from the app delegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete the persistent store, you need to close down the Core Data stack, delete the persistent store and then rebuild it the stack.

I would just use the tableview's `beginUpdate` method to freeze the table, then nil out the fetchedResults controller, then the Core Data stack. Delete the persistent store then rebuild the stack and create a new fetched results controller. Then tell the `endUpdate' and then tell the table to reload data. That should all take brief time unnoticeable by the user.